# $T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3, \dots) = (\alpha_1x_1,\alpha_2x_2,\alpha_3x_3\dots)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Kreyszig Section 8.4 Q7. Let, $T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3, \dots) = (\alpha_1x_1,\alpha_2x_2,\alpha_3x_3\dots)$ where $(\alpha_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are dense in $[0,1]$. Show that $T$ is not compact.

We have this theorem:

> The set of all eigenvalues of a compact operator on a normed linear spaces is countable.

Let, us consider the orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\ell^2$ Then $T(e_n) = \alpha_n e_n$. So $\alpha_n$ is a eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: Do you have a result about compact operators being the strong limit of finite rank operators?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, Yes we do !

Comment: You can also use that the spectrum of any operator is closed and that any nonzero element of a spectrum of a compact operator is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Your quote only works one direction.  It can happen (as your example) that an operator has countably many eigenvalues, but is not compact.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets Can we obtain something from the theorem I mentioned.

Comment: @GEdgar I am intending to show that the set of all eigenvalues is uncountable then using the theorem I quoted we can reach the solution. Right ?

Comment: I think you can use the two results I mentioned AND the theorem you mentioned :)

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets I am not sure, how to use the theorem you mentioned. Moreover, I am having doubts about how to use the theorem that I have mentioned. Would you kindly assist me on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As you already proved, all $\alpha_n$ are eigenvalues, hence the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ contains the set $\{\alpha_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
2. The spectrum is a closed set and the set $\{\alpha_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$, hence the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ contains $[0,1]$.
3. Any nonzero element of the spectrum of a compact operator is also an eigenvalue, hence elements of the interval $(0,1]$ are all eigenvalues of $T$.
4. The interval $(0,1]$ is uncountable, which contradicts the theorem you mentioned.